# Can anyone identify this painting of a Cossack?

Tags: 17th-century

Can anyone identify the name and artist of [this painting](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/a4/07/4b/a4074ba0e5baabc6a19021096f8a5377.jpg)?

[image]

Comment: Do you have reason to suspect that this painting is not modern?

Comment: I have no idea when it was painted. I have been trying to research the painting, the only information I get which may be erroneous is "17th Century Polish Cossack." Try a Google search of this quote and this is the image that comes up. This is why I have posted this is to get the truth of the art. Any thoughts or help would be great. I am sure someone must know something since it is a very nice and historically telling image.

Comment: The style suggests that this is a modern painting, showing probably a Polish/Lithuanian noble of 17-18th century, carrying a wheel-lock musket. Probably a book illustration.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That does make sense. I would like to know who did the illustration. Any idea about the banner carried by the horseman in the background? If anyone knows the book (assuming it is a book illustration)  I would like to know. This is a great forum to find out different ideas and intriguing facts not readily known. Thanks to all!!

Comment: In some searches it appears alongside works by contemporary artist [Anatoly Telenik](https://www.google.com/search?q=anatoly+telenik&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq6PfospLTAhXI7YMKHYvOAJ0QsAQIGw&biw=1366&bih=676), who has similar works. You might look through his Facebook page to see if this is in fact one of his.

Comment: @user2448131 - It looks similar to those. Same non-quite-realistic style, and dude sure seems to love his reds and browns.

Comment: Closest thing I came up with on matching banners or flags related to the Cossacks is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden%E2%80%93Ukraine_relations#/media/File:Bohdan-banner.jpg). It has *some* of the same elements.

Comment: @user2448131 - I too did a banner search, and found multiple Cossack banners with the cross in a crescent. I couldn't find anything with that squiggly (dirk?) feature though. Still the distinctive moustache, hat, and cross on top of the pole together in one person do strongly indicate Cossack. I found a few pics of Cossacks with that same mace the guy on the far left is wielding too.

Comment: The [bunchuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tug_Banner) works for the Cossacks as well.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I found the same banner [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alex_K_Kozaks_flags_1651-04.svg), which eventually brought me [here](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?534146-OFFICIAL-WIP-SUBMOD-Imperial-Splendour-2-2-1b-State-Regimental-and-Naval-Flags&p=12755728&viewfull=1#post12755728). So it would seem like it's the banner of one of the cossack's leaders that Prince Janusz Radziwill campaigned against. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_the_regions_of_Ukraine) you can see all the flags captured by Radziwill in 1651.

Comment: Y'all are awesome!! I didn't find anything under Telenik but may have a lead to a contemporary of his whom I e-mailed. The Prince Janusz banner-spot on. This forum is great!! Thank you. If I find anything, I'll post it.

Comment: No joy with my artist contact who follows Telenik. Still open to be solved. Anyone have any other ideas?